# Can't call a block on template email magento after install the security patch 6788

Tags: magento-1.8, database, email-templates, supee-6788

I have create a block on template email on magento 1.8.1

```
  {{block type="core/template" area="frontend" template="email/bankdetails.phtml" order=$order store=$store }}
```

it worked normally. But when I install a security pacth 6788, It did not work.
I checked **System > Permissions > Blocks** and I saw the blocks (core/template) are allowed for inclusion. How can I fix that problem?

Comment: Did you solved your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good Magerun addons that helps you to whitelist blocks and variables
https://github.com/peterjaap/magerun-addons#find-non-whitelisted-varsblocks-to-be-compatible-with-supee-6788-and-magento-1922

You can then add them using a data install script (eg. /app/code/local/Company/ Module/data/company_module/data-install-0.1.0.php)

```
//Make sure the upgrade is not performed on installations without the tables (i.e. unpatched shops).

$adminVersion = Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig('Mage_Admin')->version;
if (version_compare($adminVersion, '1.6.1.2', '>=')) {

$blockNames = array(
    'cms/block',
    'newsletter/subscribe',
    'onsaleslider/onsaleslider',
    'mostviewedproductslider/mostviewedproductslider'
);

foreach ($blockNames as $blockName) {
    $whitelistBlock = Mage::getModel('admin/block')->load($blockName, 'block_name');
    $whitelistBlock->setData('block_name', $blockName);
    $whitelistBlock->setData('is_allowed', 1);
    $whitelistBlock->save();
}

$variableNames = array(
    'design/email/logo_alt',
    'design/email/logo_width',
    'design/email/logo_height',
);

foreach ($variableNames as $variableName) {
    $whitelistVar = Mage::getModel('admin/variable')->load($variableName, 'variable_name');
    $whitelistVar->setData('variable_name', $variableName);
    $whitelistVar->setData('is_allowed', 1);
    $whitelistVar->save();
}
}
```

Clear the cache and post the result.